Unable to pass prop to API function from UseEffect in React Next.js
I am using App Router in next.js.
I am having trouble passing serial_num as an argument to my API function fetchImages when I am trying to trigger it from inside useEffect in my page.tsx.
/app/services/ApiService.js fetchImages
export async function fetchImages(req, res, serial_num) {
  const url = `https://my_long_url/endpoint?serial_num=${serial_num}`;
  console.log('Making API call to:', url);
  const data = await fetchAuthenticatedData(req, res, url);
  return data;
}

So, here is my page.tsx where I am trying to call this fetchImages function. Basically, I have a table in my dashboard when 'View' button is clicked it renders the following page.
/app/dashboard/[id]/page.tsx Images
import { fetchImages } from '../../../services/ApiService'

const Images = () => {
  // I am getting the serial_num here
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const serial_num = pathname.split("/").pop();

  const [mainImage, setMainImage] = useState("");
  const [selectedBlade, setSelectedBlade] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAndSetImages = async (serial_num) => {
      try {
        console.log('serial number:', serial_num); // this logs correctly
        const data = await fetchImages(serial_num);
        const bladesArray = Object.entries(data.images).map(([key, value]) => ({
          id: key,
          src: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${value}`,
        }));
        setBlades(bladesArray);
  
        if (bladesArray.length > 0) {
          setSelectedBlade(bladesArray[0].id);
          setMainImage(bladesArray[0].src);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
      }
    };
  
    if (serial_num) {
      fetchAndSetImages(serial_num);
    }
  }, [serial_num]);

The serial_num is being passed as undefined because when I log console.log('Making API call to:', url); in my fetchImages function, I get:
Making API call to: "https://my-long-url/endpoint?serial_num=undefined"
Also, if I explicitly include the serial_num in the function as follows, obviously it works fine:
export async function fetchImages(req, res, serial_num='123') {
  const url = `https://my_long_url?serial_num=${serial_num}`;
  console.log('Making API call to:', url);
  const data = await fetchAuthenticatedData(req, res, url);
  return data;
}

async function fetchAuthenticatedData(req, res, url) {
  try {
    const accessToken = await fetchAccessToken();
    const idToken = await fetchIdToken(req, res);
    console.log('Making API call to:', url);
    const fetchResponse = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'uid': idToken,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      }
    });

    if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
      const errorText = await fetchResponse.text();
      console.error('Error response:', errorText);
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${fetchResponse.status}`);
    }

    const data = await fetchResponse.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Fetch error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Function to get the ID token
export const fetchIdToken = async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession(req, res);
  return session?.idToken;
};

What I am missing?

await fetchImages(serial_num);  what happened to req / res params?

I dont know how to address them on client side since this is server side function, before I had serial_num as an argument, I was calling the function as fetchImages() and it was fine.

Your fetchImages function expects req, res, and serial_num as parameters. but you're only passing serial_num from your useEffect which will make it difficult to work in a client-side environment except you want to modify your function to either not expect req and resor provide dummy values when calling it where you don't have req and res available.
something like this:
export async function fetchImages(serial_num) {
  const url = `https://my_long_url/endpoint?serial_num=${serial_num}`;
  console.log('Making API call to:', url);
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
} --- those are for client side

// Calling fetchImages in useEffect
import { fetchImages } from '../../../services/ApiService'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const Images = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const serial_num = pathname.split("/").pop();

  const [mainImage, setMainImage] = useState("");
  const [selectedBlade, setSelectedBlade] = useState(null);
  const [blades, setBlades] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAndSetImages = async (serial_num) => {
      try {
        console.log('serial number:', serial_num);
        const data = await fetchImages(serial_num);
        const bladesArray = Object.entries(data.images).map(([key, value]) 
=> ({
          id: key,
          src: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${value}`,
        }));
        setBlades(bladesArray);

        if (bladesArray.length > 0) {
          setSelectedBlade(bladesArray[0].id);
          setMainImage(bladesArray[0].src);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
         }
    };

    if (serial_num) {
      fetchAndSetImages(serial_num);
    }
  }, [serial_num]);

  return (
    <div>
      Your JSX codes
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;


I am trying to use dummy values since I don't think I can avoid using them as my getchAuthenticatedData function requires them, can you advise what dummy values I could use or could I avoid using req/res altogether? I will add that function to my question
